# Why doesn't it increment?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, glib

So I was trying to do a function that take a `GTree*` a (each node of the `Tree` is a `struct User`) and an `id`and it would search for that `user` and increment a variable! (school project)

With some help from here, I managed to do but I didn't realize that it was not incrementing.

The structure is:

```
typedef struct user {
    int id;
    char username[256]; 
    int post_count; 
    char short_bio[16384]; 
    int reputation;
}*USER;

typedef struct TCD_community{
    GTree* res;    
    GTree* quest; 
    GTree* users; /
}TCD_community;

typedef struct TCD_community * TAD_community;

TAD_community tq;
```

And function is (helped by a stackoverflow user):

```
void incrementaPost(GTree* a,int id){

    gpointer ptr = g_tree_lookup ( a , &id);   

    struct user *u = (struct user *) ptr; 

    if(u){
        u->post_count++;  
    }
}
```

I called that on main like:

```
incrementaPost( tq -> users, 703994);
```

Output:

```
Id 703994 
Name N.Sinha 
post_count 0 
reputation 51
```

Expected:

```
Id 703994 
Name N.Sinha 
post_count 1 
reputation 51
```

Comment: We cannot tell from this code. Perhaps `g_tree_lookup` doesn't find anything, or `gpointer` is nothing like a `struct user *`, or `u` is `NULL`. Or something else is wrong.

Comment: @BoPersson maybe g_tree_lookup doesnt find anything yeah, i don't even know if i can use g_tree_lookup like that because it seems like it's not searching on the right thing of the struct, i dont know if it goes to the node and checks every variable (from the struct) that is there and compares to id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that the  `GTree*` has to be properly constructed before you can do the search.

First construct the tree with the dedicated search function:

```
GTree   *tree;
tree = g_tree_new(MySearchFunction);
```

Where

> `g_tree_new ()`
>
> `GTree * g_tree_new (GCompareFunc key_compare_func);`
>
> Creates a new `GTree`.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `key_compare_func`
>
> the function used to order the nodes in the `GTree`. It should return
>   values similar to the standard `strcmp()` function -`0` if the two
>   arguments are equal, a negative value if the first argument comes
>   before the second, or a positive value if the first argument comes
>   after the second.

Then your objects have to inserted using `g_tree_insert ()`

> `g_tree_insert ()`
>
> `void g_tree_insert (GTree *tree,
>                  gpointer key,
>                  gpointer value);`
>
> Inserts a key/value pair into a `GTree`.
>
> If the given key already exists in the `GTree` its corresponding value
>   is set to the new value. If you supplied a value_destroy_func when
>   creating the `GTree`, the old value is freed using that function. If
>   you supplied a key_destroy_func when creating the `GTree`, the passed
>   key is freed using that function.
>
> Parameters
>
> `tree`
>
> - a `GTree`
>
> `key`
>
> - the key to insert
>
> `value`
>
> - the value corresponding to the key

Only then, you can use `g_tree_lookup` for the search.

[Check this simple example](https://github.com/steshaw/gtk-examples/blob/master/ch02.glib/tree.c) - how to construct `GTree*`, insert elements, do the search via `g_tree_lookup` and traverse the tree via `g_tree_traverse`.